# Table for actual values

Tags: mysql, join, data-warehouse

I have a database where logging happens and is processed in a data-warehouse styled environment. This means there are staging cycles where the data comes in and then is processed. For a reporting system, some log entries for certain parameters need to read, although it can happen that there are no entries in the staging cycle. Therefore there is a table which contains a value for every parameter - the last one which has been read. After the processing finished, the table is updated via

```
UPDATE jobcontrol.actual_values a
JOIN jobcontrol.processing p
SET a.value = p.value 
WHERE p.t_ns = (select max(p.t_ns) from jobcontrol.processing p WHERE a.para_id = p.para_id) 
AND a.para_id = p.para_id;
```

This seems improvable to me, although my try to simplify it via a real join didn't quite work.

Do you have any suggestions on how this could work more easily (and faster)?

`-> Explain Statement (This was run on a test table with 36 rows for 8 different parameters)`

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p     | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |   36 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | jobcontrol.p.para_id |    1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p     | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | jobcontrol.a.para_id |    2 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
```

`-> SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `processing` (
  `para_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t_ns` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_inst` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `isanchor` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`para_id`,`t_ns`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

MySQL Version is 5.6

Comment: The minimum information that we need to help you is: MySQL version, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` from the tables involved, `EXPLAIN` on the query or (if using MySQL < 5.6) equivalent `SELECT`.

Comment: I edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the Query to the following:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE jobcontrol.actual_values a
    JOIN jobcontrol.processing p ON a.para_id = p.para_id
    SET a.value = (select p.value from jobcontrol.processing p WHERE a.para_id = p.para_id ORDER BY t_ns DESC LIMIT 1)
```

- The `JOIN ON` makes the recordset smaller (DB checks only the parameters which are also in processing, not every single one. The `EXPLAIN` however indicates that we at least use an index now)
- In the `SELECT` : Replacing the `MAX()` with a `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` should boost the performance a bit, especially for big tables. If `MAX()` uses a filesort (like `ORDER BY ... DESC` does) nothing should change.

  ```
  +----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-----------------------------+ 
  | id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra                       |
  +---+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-----------------------------+
  |  1 | PRIMARY            | p     | index  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 12      | NULL                 |   36 | Using index                 |
  |  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | jobcontrol.p.para_id |    1 | NULL                        |
  |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p     | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | jobcontrol.a.para_id |    2 | Using where; Using filesort |
  +----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-----------------------------+
  ```